# Count rows which have date less than max date

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset which contains different entries with dates assgined to each entry. I have created a new measure which will calculate the max date among the dates present in the dataset.

I want to countrows where the entries have date less than the max date.

Suppose the max date is 12th June, any entry with date less than 12th June should get counted.

Thanks for the help.

I have tried few expressions but they have not returned any value or the desired value.

Comment: COUNTROWS(
FILTER('MyTable', [Date]< MAX('MyTable'[Date]) )
)